# how to use MongoDB in laravel4?

Tags: php, mongodb

I have successfully installed Mongodb on my win 7 system. I also installed php extension for MongoDB on my Wamp server and it works perfectly; yet I wish to know how I can use MongoDB in my laravel4 projects. I will like to use mongovel package but when I run 'composer update' there is always an error: **php extension not found in your system**. Also I installed jessengers package but got an error: **MongoClient not available**. Please I need help on how to get out of this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that the extension is *also* available on the command line. In many cases there is a different php.ini for CLI. You can find this out by running:

```
php --ri mongo
```

if that does not provide any sort of output about version and settings, you don't have it installed properly.

Then you can use `php --ini` to find out where your INI files are - the ones that are used for running PHP on the command line